# Match value in pandas cell where value is array using np.where (ValueError: Arrays were different lengths)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

many thanks for your reading.

(Prior consideration: I cannot change the format of the data inside the dataframes; I'm stuck with what I have. The following is a simplified and reduced version of my data and problem)

I have a dataframe with the following form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'Machine': [['red', 'blue'], ['red'], ['blue'], ['No Match']]})

       Machine       
0  [red, blue]  
1        [red]   
2       [blue]      
3   [No Match]
```

I want to  create a new column, `TF`, which returns, for a given row, `True` if the value in `Machine` is equal to `['No Match']` and `False` otherwise.

```
       Machine     TF  
0  [red, blue]    False
1        [red]    False
2       [blue]    False
3   [No Match]    True
```

To do this, I can write:

```
df['TF'] = np.where(df['Machine'] == ['No Match'],True, False)
```

I get this output:

```
ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 4 vs 1
```

The reason for this is that numpy expects `df['Machine']` and `['No Match']` to be of equal length, or for the right hand criterion to be a simple string/value.

### How can I adjust this expression to succesfully pass the array `['No match']` as a value into the `np.where()` statement?

As an example of what does work, for the following dataframe, everything works as expected:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
{'Machine': [['red', 'blue'], ['red'], ['blue'], 'No Match']})

df1['TF'] = np.where(df1['Machine'] == 'No Match',True, False)
```

Works as expected:

```
       Machine     TF
0  [red, blue]  False
1        [red]  False
2       [blue]  False
3     No Match   True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `apply` with `==` for check values in `list`:

```
df['TF'] = np.where(df['Machine'].apply(lambda x: ['No Match'] == x),True, False)
print (df)
       Machine     TF
0  [red, blue]  False
1        [red]  False
2       [blue]  False
3   [No Match]   True
```

Or simplier if need only `True` and `False`:

```
df['TF'] = df['Machine'].apply(lambda x: ['No Match'] == x)
print (df)
       Machine     TF
0  [red, blue]  False
1        [red]  False
2       [blue]  False
3   [No Match]   True
```

But if need some another values:

```
df['TF'] = np.where(df['Machine'].apply(lambda x: ['No Match'] == x),'a', 'b')
print (df)
       Machine TF
0  [red, blue]  b
1        [red]  b
2       [blue]  b
3   [No Match]  a
```

Solution with `list comprehension`:

```
df['TF'] = [['No Match'] == x for x in df['Machine']]
print (df)
       Machine     TF
0  [red, blue]  False
1        [red]  False
2       [blue]  False
3   [No Match]   True
```

Comment: It works. But I get the warning: `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Comment: Problem is in sample or in real data?

Comment: real data - I must have missed something of the formats when I simplified the dataframe.

Comment: There can be more problems check [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) but maybe need add `copy`

Comment: Thanks for the link - I will read, and try and solve. many thanks for your speedy, correct answer!

Comment: Or there can be problem after boolean indexing -  need `df1 = df[df['col'] == 1 ].copy()`

Comment: Another explanation is [here](http://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-1.html) - check title `SettingWithCopy`.